# Get the sum of the 2 row values

Tags: php, mysql

My table structure is as follows

```
**ID**     **datefrom**         **dateto**    **amount**
  1         2011-03-01          2011-03-04      3500
  2         2011-03-05          2011-03-10      2500
```

I need to search in both rows and get the sum of the amount and number of rows

I need to retrieve all the rows which are between the user input 2 date values, from date and to date. I write a query as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount, COUNT(amount) as numcount 
FROM rate 
WHERE "2011-03-03" BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto 
AND "2011-03-06" BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto
```

But its not working as I expected, I need to search all the datefrom and dateto rows to find the given dates and get the number of the rows and the sum of the amount, pls somebody help me with the correct query

Comment: When you say it is not working...  What are the results you are getting and can you describe what results you are expecting?

Comment: @Rocket: Thanks a lot to make my code easily visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We aren't sure yet what results you are expecting, but should you be using `OR` instead of `AND` for the two date ranges?

```
WHERE "2011-03-03" BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto 
OR "2011-03-06" BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto
```

Comment: Hi Micheal, thanks a lot for your help, it worked, thanks a lot for you kind help